# SQL write a file with a file number incremented by 1 every time

Tags: sql, file, filenames

In sql I am currently writing out a CSV file called "TodaysData". I want to be able to name it with a number at the end so every time the job executes it out puts the file name with the incremented number e.g

TodaysData.001
TodaysData.002
TodaysData.003 etc

Please can someone help me with the code for this

Answer (score 0):

There is number of ways you can do it. One of the easiest would be to store value in table since this job can execute multiple time per day.

```
CREATE TABLE MyFileCountTable
    (
     File_Date DATE
    ,File_Count INT
    )


DECLARE @FileCount INT;

IF (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE File_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
   ) = 0
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), 1)
        SET @FileCount = 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @FileCount = File_Count
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE File_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    END

--Code here to produce the file and append @FileCount

UPDATE MyTable
    SET File_Count = File_Count + 1
    WHERE File_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```